# move local users from windows 2003 to windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, users

I want to move local users account form windows 2003 to windows 2008.( users dont exist in domain or AD)
I create a list of users , I will set new password for them , but is there any way to create users from a text file in windows 2008 , I have about 200 users.
Can I import my user list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=199878

Addusers.exe allow to transfer users (but not passwords) via text files. Hope it helps.

Comment: as I read this tools dont applied for windows 2008,can I used it ?

Comment: I've used it successfully with Windows 2003 server (also don't applied), so just try... 

The other possible way - migration using export/inport with PowerShell (you will need to install PS to Windows 2003) as described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379531%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I have windows web server 2008 R2, and I can't find migration tools on it. can I install this feature?

Comment: Sorry, but it seems (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379545%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_supported) Windows server Migration tools not availible as feature with Windows Server Web edition.